¿Se pueden dar estilos a la etiqeta <title>?
Me gustaría saber si se pueden poner clases o id's para darle estilos o efectos con pseudo clases

No, no puedes. Antes se le ponía efectos con marquee pero eso ya es obsoleto y nada recomendable. Para que quieres poner estilos al Título de la pestaña del navegador??

me gustaría hacerle un efecto a las letras del titulo puesto que se puede hacer que se muevan con js y me gustaría darle un brillo con css para que al usar un hover o focus  y js el brillo siga las letras como hace el navegador Brave con las pestañas

De que hablas? Yo uso Brave y nunca he visto nada de eso. Puedes poner un ejemplo y por favor cuando logres lo que quieres también pon el código, esto lo quiero ver

presta atención a la pestaña del navegador al usar Brave y notaras, al menos en el modo oscuro, que la ventana a la que señales(no en la que estés tiene que ser otra) se torna mas brillante y el brillo sigue el mouse

Pero eso no tiene que ver con el tag <title>  Eso va a pasar en tu web igual, es algo de Brave no de la web per se. Pero vuelvo a repetir, cuando des con la solución la pones acá, esto lo quiero ver

Hola te recomiendo hacer el [tour] para que vayas aprendiendo como funciona el sitio, saludos.

claro, pero es solo del navegador Brave, quedaría mucho mejor poder implementarlo en otros navegadores. Y si lo consigo lo hago

@LeonardoRodoni Si lo quieres para brave te recomiendo usar la etiqueta correspondiente

Que la respuesta a la pregunta sea un "no es posible" no hace invalida la pregunta ni es motivo de cierra

No se puede.
Recuerda que el elemento <title> no es un elemento visual, pertenece a los meta-datos de la página:
De acuerdo a la especificación

The title element represents the document's title or name. Authors should use titles that identify their documents even when they are used out of context, for example in a user's history or bookmarks, or in search results

Mi traducción libre:

El elemento title representa el título o nombre del documento. Los autores debieran usar títulos que identifiquen sus documentos aún cuando estos son usados fuera de contexto, por ejemplo en el historial del usuario, en los marcadores del navegador o en resultados de búsqueda.

El resaltado es mío.
La W3 School, por otro lado, nos aclara su uso:

The  tag defines the title of the document. The title must be text-only, and it is shown in the browser's title bar or in the page's tab.
...
The  element:

defines a title in the browser toolbar
provides a title for the page when it is added to favorites
displays a title for the page in search-engine results


No traduciré más pero, en resumen, pienso que, ya a estas alturas te darás cuenta que no sería razonable esperar que puedas agregar efectos o animaciones a algo que va a aparecer dentro de los marcadores del usuario, en los resultados de Google/Bing/Etc, o en las pestañas del navegador y, sin embargo, no aparece en ningún lugar del documento.
Porque ese texto no es visible dentro del documento mismo, que es dónde las hojas de estilo tienen efecto.
